# how to deploy terraform directly from an existing typescript project

Tags: typescript, terraform, terraform-cdk

I wish to deploy infrastructure that is commonly based on terraform directly using typescript/node.js code. I know there is a cdk for terraform (which you can use in typescript) - however, the documentation only seems to give instructions for doing this in a completely new project. However, I already have an existing project and thus I cannot just run the `init` command. Does anyone know what requirements there are to use `cdktf` in an existing typescript file, beyond just running `yarn add cdktf`? e.g. how would I generate the right cdktf.json file?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use CDKTF to programmatically run a deployment (e.g. calling a method to run TF apply from node) [yet](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-cdk/issues/804). You can also not run plain terraform code from CDKTF yet, but you can use [modules](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cdktf/concepts/modules). You can also move  your TF code over to CDKTF by running `cdktf init --from-terraform-project` which uses convert to translate your code.